# Use non-blocking communication with Java binding of OpenMPI (IsSend and Recv)

Tags: java, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to translate an example mpi program in c# (called rotate.c) using Java binding of OpenMPI, which involves non-blocking communication with isSend and Recv function.

Below is the c# code I am attempting to translate into java.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(){
  int rank, size, tag;
  int start,stop,i;
  int left, right, addon, passon, sum;
  MPI_Comm comm;
  MPI_Status status;
  MPI_Request request;

  comm  = MPI_COMM_WORLD;

  tag = 1;

  MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
  MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);            
  MPI_Comm_size(comm, &size); 

  //Send current number to the right and receive from the left
  left = rank -1;
  right = rank + 1;
  if ((rank+1) == size){
    right = 0;
  }
  if(rank == 0){
    left = size - 1;
  }

  sum = 0;

  // Initialise local values to:
  passon = (rank+1)*(rank+1);

  // Use non-blocking point-to-point communication

  for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    MPI_Issend(&passon,1,MPI_INT,right,tag,comm,&request);
    MPI_Recv(&addon,1,MPI_INT,left,tag,comm,&status);
    MPI_Wait(&request,&status);

    sum = sum + addon;
    passon = addon;

  }

  printf( "The sum is: %d on processor %d \n",sum, rank);
  MPI_Finalize();

}
```

In particular, I am having difficulty translating the following section in Java. The main issue is that in Java OpenMPI, MPI_IsSend only takes Buffer object, while MPI_Recv can take a java.lang Object.

```
 for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    MPI_Issend(&passon,1,MPI_INT,right,tag,comm,&request);
    MPI_Recv(&addon,1,MPI_INT,left,tag,comm,&status);
    MPI_Wait(&request,&status);

    sum = sum + addon;
    passon = addon;

  }
```

Consequently, I have been using ByteBuffer (example below) but I am running into segfault error (SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f5da501fe5a, pid=431798, tid=0x00007f5da6541700). If I use ByteBuffer in the Recv function, I also get the same error.

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++){
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(passon.length);
            bb.put(passon);
            Request r = comm.isSend(bb,1,MPI.BYTE,right,tag);
            Status r2 = comm.recv(addon,1,MPI.BYTE,left,tag);
            r.waitStatus();
            //MPI_Wait(&request,&status);

            sum = sum + (int)addon[0];
            passon = addon;

        }
```

My main questions are:

1. Is it possible to write an equivalent Java OpenMPI program for the c# code?
2. Is there a simpler way to perform non-blocking communication using Java OpenMPI?

> **Solution**
>
> As suggested by Gilles, MPI_Sendrecv() appears to perform similarly to
>   the three MPI calls in C.
>
> The minimal example of the code is as follows:
>
> ```
> public class testMPI {
>
>     public static void main(String [] args) throws MPIException {
>
>         int rank, size;
>         int left, right, sum;
>         int[] passon = new int[1];
>         int[] addon = new int[1];
>
>         MPI.Init(args);
>         rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.getRank();
>         size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.getSize();
>
>         //Send current number to the right and receive from the left
>         left = rank -1;
>         right = rank + 1;
>         if ((rank+1) == size){
>             right = 0;
>         }
>         if(rank == 0){
>             left = size - 1;
>         }
>
>         sum = 0;
>
>         // Initialise local values to:
>         passon[0] = (rank+1)*(rank+1);
>
>         // Use non-blocking point-to-point communication
>
>           for(i=0;i<size;i++){
>
>             MPI.COMM_WORLD.sendRecv(passon, passon.length, MPI.INT, right, 1, addon, addon.length, MPI.INT, left, 1);
>             sum = sum + addon[0];
>             passon = addon;
>
>
>         }
>
>         System.out.printf("The sum is: %d on processor %d \n",sum, rank);
>         MPI.Finalize();
>
>     } 
> }
> ```

Comment: Welcome to SO! please post your Java [MCVE]. If you can use `MPI_Isend()` instead of `MPI_Issend()`, then simply issue a single `MPI_Sendrecv()` call instead of the three MPI calls.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - MPI_Sendrecv() works perfectly. I will post a minimal example so that it may be helpful to others.